# How do I get the value of a node with XPath?

Tags: php, xpath

How do I get the value of a node with XPath?

**Get all nodes which have a price above 35**

```
/bookstore/book[price>35.00]
```

But when I change the > to an = for equals, the query fails.
Please help. By the way I'm using php, but that shouldn't matter as XPath is universal.

**Here's the php code and xml code I was using**

```
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
 <bookstore>
 <book>
   <title lang=\"eng\">Harry Potter</title>
   <price>29.99</price>
 </book>
 <book>
   <title lang=\"eng\">Learning XML</title>
   <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
 </bookstore>"; $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $name = 'Shiny Red';
    $nodes = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/bookstore/book[price>35.00]', $name));
    if (!empty($nodes)) {
        printf('At least one building named "%s" found<hr/>', $name);
    echo "<textarea style=\"width: 400px; height: 300px;\">";print_r($nodes); echo "</textarea>";
    } else {
        printf('No building named "%s" found', $name);
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to say without a sample of your XML.

Comment: Next to an XML sample, as you want to return a value, you should add your example PHP code as well.

Comment: Not in a position to test, but have you tried `/bookstore/book/[number(price)=35.00]` ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it fails? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Wrikken - I think you have an extra `/` in there before the predicate.

Comment: @LarsH true, was a bit hasty. Pretend it's not there ;)

Comment: I've updated my question with a code sample, so you can assist me in answering my question.

Comment: The code sample is helpful. The next step would be to answer Michael Kay's question.

Comment: To answer your question Michael, here's what happens when I change [price>35.00] in the code sample to [price.39.95]. There is no fatal error. Basically I must be doing something wrong, although the XPath syntax does advise in using `=`


`No building named "Shiny Red" found`

Comment: @desbest:  Now is the opportunity to get value for your bounty -- edit the question and ask for more challenging tasks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//bookstore/book/price[. ='35.00']
```

or

```
//bookstore/book[price='35.00']
```

The trick is in the quotes. Node values are text. You won't match anything with '35.00' however, but that is because your XML doesn't contain books with that price. Matching '39.95' will work (tested).

```
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
 <bookstore>
 <book>
   <title lang=\"eng\">Harry Potter</title>
   <price>29.99</price>
 </book>
 <book>
   <title lang=\"eng\">Learning XML</title>
   <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
 </bookstore>"; $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $name = 'Shiny Red';
    $nodes = $xml->xpath(sprintf('//bookstore/book/price[. = \'39.95\']', $name));
    if (!empty($nodes)) {
        printf('At least one building named "%s" found<hr/>', $name);
    echo "<textarea style=\"width: 400px; height: 300px;\">";print_r($nodes); echo "</textarea>";
    } else {
        printf('No building named "%s" found', $name);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Before I offered a bounty, the question was collecting dust for 3 weeks going unanswered.

Comment: Yes. I think it was kicked to the top because of that bounty. I'm confused though that no-one posted this answer before. :)

Comment: What if I wanted an XPath that looked for both the title and price at once? I tried using the `and` operator, and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hey, there's a new bounty for that? ;-)

Comment: `$nodes = $xml->xpath(sprintf('//bookstore/book[(price = \'39.95\') and (title = \'Learning XML\')]', $name));`

Comment: Note there is no `/` after `book`. I did this wrong in my answer, but I've corrected this.